# Calculate maximum sum of values over any 30 days period

Tags: algorithm, math

I have data as follows:

```
Date        Value
2011-01-01  1
2011-01-02  5
2011-01-03  30
   .....
2012-01-01  4
```

I want to calculate which 30 day period within my data that has the maximum sum of values.

Not sure if my question makes sense as it's quite difficult to explain as I don't have a good maths head.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: What part bothers you? Calculating a running 30 days sum value or finding the maximum value?

Comment: I assume the date format is YYYY-MM-DD? It makes less sense otherwise. Is the data in date order, and are their missing dates?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The maximum value is what I am after. The date format is in YYYY-MM-DD and yes the data is in date order with no missing dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you.  It assumes a zero (0) based array system.

```
sum <- 0
for i = 0 to 29
  sum <- sum + value(i)

max <- sum
start <- 0

for i = 30 to value.lengh-1
  sum <- sum - value(i-30) + value(i)
  if sum > max then
    max <- sum
    start <- i-29
```

Here `max` contains the maximum sum of 30 consecutive values and `start` contains the starting point of that 30 day max run.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've this solution and it works a treat for me. I still need to do further testing but it what I am after!

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
MaxStartDate = FirstDate
MaxTotal = -1   (something that is definitely below your possible total)

for n=0 to lastDate-30
{
    tempMax = 0

    for m=n to n+29
        tempMax = tempMax + date(m)

    if tempMax > MaxTotal
    {
        MaxTotal = tempMax
        MaxStartDate = date(n)
    }
}
```

When the for loop finishes, MaxTotal will be your highest 30 day total and MaxStartDate will be the first day in the 30 day set.

Comment: The code above my post is more elegant but it has an error and I can't comment on it....   at the end start_date = date(i+1) is the correct line NOT start_date = date(30+i).

Answer (score 0):

```
for first 30 days in your data, compute the sum of all values
let this be called as max_sum
let start_date be the first date in the input data

Loop 'i' from 1 to (total dates - 30)
    temp_sum = (temp_sum + value of date (30+i) - value of date (i))
    if max_sum < temp_sum
       max_sum = temp_sum
       start_date= ith date
```

Final value of `max_sum` is the maximum sum of values over any 30 days period with `start_date` as the start point.

Comment: -1; This has a couple of logical errors. The first one Justin Paulson alludes to below. You also do not consistently retain a running total of any 30-day span; the only time you update max_sum is when the condition is satisfied, which in many cases it won't be satisfied. If you fix the errors, or convince me I'm wrong, I'll remove the -1.